# Unable to send mail via php mail()

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

I am unable to send an email via php's mail function.

This is the error I receive.
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in D:\inetpub\vhosts\southernbatteries.com\httpdocs\includes\utils.php on line 6
Array ( [0] => [1] => Could not send mail, please try later... )

What exactly does this mean ? Does it mean there is not mail server installed on my webserver ? Is it possible to use a different mail server. E.g Gmails mail server to send the mail ?

Comment: Do you run your own web server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use built-in `mail()`, you will need to talk to the server administrator. It is possible to use an external SMTP server on Windows, but it has to be specified in the php.ini settings, and PHP's built-in functions don't support SMTP authentication.

The usual way is to either use a local mail server that in turn can talk to a "real" SMTP server *with* authentication, or use a mailing package like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) that can connect to a 3rd party SMTP server like GMail directly.

Comment: Thing is, I am trying to help out a friend and they don't know the details of the hosting service.

If I were to upload the SwiftMailer files to the webserver, will I be able to send Mails using that ?

Comment: @Prakash yes, it will work independently from  `mail()`. If the server is not misconfigured, you should be able to work with it. See http://www.swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v3/connections/smtp for a GMail example

Comment: According to the example it connects to localhost:25. And according to the error my page throws, 25 might not be open "Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" "

This is a section phpinfo() 
SMTP localhost localhost
smtp_port 25 25

Do things look ok ?

Comment: @Prakash those are separate examples (it's arguably a bit confusing). Use the one prefixed `//Connect to Gmail (PHP5)`

Comment: @Pekka: I have a doubt. Does SwiftMailer require my server to have a mail server running ? Or is it completely independent of it ?

Comment: @Prakash it is supposed to be completely independent. It connects directly to the remote SMTP server

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a mail server to send mails. If you only have apache, you cannot, unless you [edit the php.ini file and set the smpt_server](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/Configure_PHP_to_Use_a_Remote_SMTP_Server_for_Sending_Mail.htm) to one that allows you to do so. Note that this will only work depending on your ISP.

If you have a hosting account you can upload the files and online they will work.

Comment: Some of the lines from phpinfo() are

SMTP localhost localhost
smtp_port 25 25
Internal Sendmail Support for Windows enabled
sendmail_from help@internetworldwide.org help@internetworldwide.org

It does look ok right ? Should I look for something else to ensure that a mail server is running ?

Answer (score 0):

You should run your own mailserver on your server. Most likely it's not started or not installed.

As I can see your are running it on windows it's most likely the later. You could try using your providers mail server. Or googles. But you need most likely a username and password for that.

Comment: don't you mean "[...]run your own **mail**server[...]"?

Comment: How could I use Googles mail server, since it would work out if the mail were to be sent from my gmail account ?

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid using php's mail()-function as ist connects and disconnects to the mailserver for every mail sent.

instead of that, try to use something like [phpMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) wich allows easy configuration and sending a lot of mails without performance-problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your own mail server (if this is a development environment for example) you could use [mercury](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercury.htm).

Comment: I don't have too much freedom with the hosting server. It is a Windows system (that is all I know) and I might not be able to install anything on it.